# rails solr search limit total search results / get fixed number of results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, solr, sunspot-rails, sunspot-solr

I'm trying to perform a search, order the results randomly, and only return a number of results, not all matches. Something like limit(2)
I've tried using the Solr param 'rows' but that doesn't seem to do anything:

```
@featured_articles = Article.search do 
  with(:is_featured, true)
  order_by :random
  adjust_solr_params do |params|
    params[:rows] = 2
  end
end
```

@featured_articles.total should be 2, but it returns more than 2

How can I get a randomized fixed number of results?

Answer (score 1):

Rather than adjusting params, just add a line:

```
order_by :random
rows :2
```

See here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/CommonQueryParameters

Answer (score 0):

All ruby example..

```
@featured_articles = Article.search do 
  with(:is_featured, true)
  order_by :random
end.shuffle.take(2)
```

If you don't need Solr, depending on your db, you could also do: `Article.where(is_featured: true).order("RANDOM()").limit(2)`